# How to copy an Azure SQL Database to a different server or subscription using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am trying to copy Azure SQL Database to a different server, and for this I am following this document
[ https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-copy-an-azure-sql-database...][1]

I used same credentials for user and login creation at source and destination server. I captured the SID of a user from source server and created a login with the same SID at destination server.

login name: Sana1

username: sanauser

I performed the same steps mentioned in the document for automation account creation. Now, i'm getting below errors with two different scenarios:

1.In the credential tab when i am using Login Name in the user name field -
[image 1 ][2]

2. In the credential tab when i am using User Name in the user name field -[image 2][3]

thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled

I am not able to connect to destination server to copy database by using above steps. Anyone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new credential asset with the Azure portal**

1. From your Automation account, on the left-hand pane select
   Credentials under Shared Resources.
2. On the Credentials page, select Add a credential.

> 3. **In the New Credential pane, enter an `appropriate credential name`**
>    **following your naming standards.**

4. Type your access ID in the User name field.
5. For both password fields, enter your secret access key.
6. If the multi-factor authentication box is checked, uncheck it.
7. Click Create to save the new credential asset.

[image]

> **Note: Azure Automation does not support user accounts that use
> multi-factor authentication**.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=azure-powershell#create-a-new-credential-asset-with-the-azure-portal) is the MSFT Doc with further details.